# How to custom a home shop page with all products?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm trying to set-up a home shop page with specific content on it.

My menu contains all categories and I want to switch of category when I click on each item. 
My problem is :
- I want to set-up my homepage with banner content above all products category (link "tous)
- I don't want this banner content appears on others categories.

I'm using Woocommerce on wordpress.

Many thanks for your help
Thib

Comment: Only show banner on the home page by putting if condition if (is_home && is_front_page) then show image@Thibaut

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress theme, create a file called woocommerce.php This gives a you idea of how: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Once you add/create the woocommerce.php file to your theme then you can add the image banner above  `woocommerce_content()`

If you want to target just the main shop page, you can use is_shop() but to add a function in your functions.php then you want to wrap it with:

```
if function_exists(is_shop()) {
  //add code here
}
```